# Mermaid DiagrammeR journey

Tags: r-markdown, diagrammer, mermaid, journey

How can I solve this problem. I added the following line of code in my *.rmd file:

```
DiagrammeR::mermaid("
journey
    title My working day
    section Go to work
      Make tea: 5: Me
      Go upstairs: 3: Me
      Do work: 1: Me, Cat
    section Go home
      Go downstairs: 5: Me
      Sit down: 5: Me
")
```

I use the R package distill to knit a distill_website. Only the journey diagramm is not generated.
I can see in the html-file a white space but no diagramm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start by installing the development version of DiagrammeR from GitHub using the devtools package and see the difference:

```
devtools::install_github("rich-iannone/DiagrammeR")
```

It's seems that [Journey Diagram](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/) is yet to be implemented.
So, for quick (and temporary) solution (works perfectly with `distill::distill_article`) you may

> deploy mermaid without a bundler, one can insert a `script` tag with an
> absolute address and a `mermaidAPI` call into the HTML like so:

````
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<script>mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});</script>

```{r diagram-mermaid, echo = FALSE}
DiagrammeR::mermaid(diagram = '
journey
    title My working day
    section Go to work
      Make tea: 5: Me
      Go upstairs: 3: Me
      Do work: 1: Me, Cat
    section Go home
      Go downstairs: 5: Me
      Sit down: 5: Me
', height = '100%', width = '100%')
```
````

> Doing so will command the mermaid parser to look for the `<div>`
> tags with `class="mermaid"`. From these tags mermaid will try to
> read the diagram/chart definitons and render them into svg charts.

Does this help in any way with `distill::distill_website`?

Comment: Hello Radovan, yes it is working! Thanks for your help. distill_website looks great. Sebastian

Comment: Glad I could help.